# how can I do the following integration?

Tags: definite-integrals

$$
\int_0^h\!\exp\left( ity + (\alpha-1) \ln y \right)\,dy,
$$
where $i = \sqrt{-1}$,
 $\alpha>0$,  and $h>0$.

Please show your work step by step.

I know 
$$
\int\! \exp \left( mx \right)\,dx = \frac{\exp ( mx )}{m} + c,
$$
 where $c$ is a constant.
So I have done :
$$
\int\!\exp\left( ity + (\alpha-1) \ln y\right) dy
=  \frac{exp \left(ity + (\alpha-1) \ln y\right)}{it + (\alpha-1)\frac{1}{y}} 
$$
is this right?

Alternative method is not coming in my mind.

Comment: I think that you would be better received if you took the time to use proper spelling, capitalization, and grammar.

Comment: It is also near impossible as written to tell what you are trying to integrate.

Comment: ∫(0 to h) exp [ ity + (α-1) ln y ] dy

Comment: @tree, please *edit* the question to correct typos at least.

Comment: @tree What about $t$?

Comment: @srijan t is a constant . Only the variable is y.

Comment: @tree do you *really* want $i$ to be any imaginary number, or do you mean $i = \sqrt{-1}$?

Comment: @Stahl i = √(-1)

Comment: @Stahl Thank you very much for reforming my question. Where can i learn LaTex so that i will feel comfortable to join in this site?

Comment: You might want to simplify the integrand by using some facts about exponentials, e.g., $e^{a+b}=e^ae^b$, $e^{ab}=(e^b)^a$, and $e^{\log a}=a$.

Comment: If you check the faq it will direct you to some discussions of LaTeX we've had.

Comment: @tree in particular, [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/117#117) is a starting point for formatting some $\LaTeX$.